# Can't convert html to JSON

Tags: python, json, automation, python-requests

```
import json,requests,sys,os

url='https://www.timeanddate.com'
response=requests.get(url).text
data=json.loads(response.text)
weatherData=response.json(response)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' has object has no attribute 'json'
```

Comment: Ummm, `response` is already text (line 4). Then you're again calling `response.text`.

Answer (score 1):

What is this line `weatherData=response.json(response)`?
I think this will be work

```
import json
response=requests.get(url)
weatherData=json.loads(response.text)
```

Now `weatherData` is a python dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the URL in the question is the actual URL and you are actually trying to convert all the HTML in the response into a JSON, it won't be possible. HTML and JSON are not convertible formats. You will have to find an API URL that will return actual JSON data. Maybe you want to checkout https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/
2. If the URL in the question is a dummy URL and you are using an actual URL which returns a JSON response, then see the requests documentation here for how to get the JSON from the response. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content